# How to pivot in Pandas dataframe

Tags: azure-databricks

Please advise how it can be done in Pandas dataframe :

```
Current in the Pandas dataframe(df)          
Id    Phone     Email        workplace  Mailing city   Mailing Stat
123   12345    123@1233.de     test      New York        New York 
abc   45678    abc@ab.de       test      New York        New York
def   78019    def@def.de       test     New York        New York
```

I am looking in the below mentioned format in the pandas dataframe

```
id      Attribute     Value             Mailing city    Mailing sat
123      Phone       12345               New York       New York
123      Email       123@1233.de         New York       New York
123     workplace    test                New York       New York
abc      phone       45678               New York       New York
abc      email     abc@ab.de             New York       New York
abc     workplace   test
```

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced this and got the below results by using melt function.

**Pandas dataframe**:

[image]

**Code for required result:**

```
import pandas as pd

result_df= pd.melt(p_df, id_vars="Id", value_vars=["Phone","Email","workplace"],var_name="Attribute", value_name="Value")
result_df=result_df.sort_values('Id')
result_df
```

**Execution:**

[image]

Comment: But there are other columns are present in the dataframe how i need to select those columns in this particular dataframe

Comment: You can give all columns apart from `Id` dynamically like this `result_df= pd.melt(p_df, id_vars="Id", value_vars=p_df.columns[1:],var_name="Attribute", value_name="Value")`. If your `id_vars` is not `Id` use the list `p_df.column` and make another list without that column and use it.

Comment: when i use the above code .I am getting The Python process exited with exit code 137 (SIGKILL: Killed). This may have been caused by an OOM error. Check your command's memory usage.

Comment: I have rechecked it with the above columns and it is working fine for me. The above error seems to be more related to the Memory. Try to restart the databricks cluster or change the cluster configurations and recheck.